# Use QAbstractTableModel implementation with a QList of custom classes

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qabstracttablemodel

I have a general question about the implementation of the underlying data source of a `QAbstractTableModel`.

The `QAbstractTableModel::data()` function access the data sources content by an index consisting of a row and a column value.

If my underlying data source is a `QList` of `Person` classes, where each member represents a column, how do I access its members with a given column index?

The only approach I can think of is that I use a kind of mapping, that maps a column number to a member of the `Person` class:

```
QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        Person person = mySource[index.row()];

        if (index.column() == 0)
            return person.getName();
        else if (index.column() == 1)
            return person.getAdress();
        (...and so on..)
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

Is this the approach to tackle this problem or is there a better one? If my class has 50 members that would be a lot of work to do. The same thing must be done, when I write data to the source via `QAbstractTableModel::setData()`.

Answers or links to material that would help me to understand this part of the model/view implementation in Qt are very much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the approach to tackle this problem or is there a better one?

Certainly a valid approach, yes. There is no introspection feature for this even with [QMetaObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qmetaobject.html).

> If my class has 50 members that would be a lot of work to do. The same thing must be done, when I write data to the source via QAbstractTableModel::setData().

Well, it is very unlikely you will ever get 50 different members, but in that case, managing your class would be inherently complex anyway.

> Answers or links to material that would help me to understand this part of the model/view implementation in Qt are very much appriciated.

There is not much to link here, really. See above for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer to my problem. Not quite sure how it all will work out in detail, but I think thats the way to go ().

> [...] Although the model methods operate on items using the item index concept, sometimes it is not possible or convinient to pinpoint the representation of the item just using the row and column numbers and an index of the parent. Fortunately the index carries more than that. A pointer (void*) or an additional number (int) can be associated with an index, which can point to the internal data representation of the item (either a pointer to a data structure or an index of an element in an array, map or something simmilar). Thanks to that mechanism, methods can have direct access to data structures representing items.

from http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=QAbstractItemModel#Implementing_custom_models